# Windows Phone 7 - update database without changing user data

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-7

I am creating application with data in database. Database has several columns and one I want to change by user. That would be column with boolean values (true|false). By default all rows have false value. User can change this to true. Now I have created many rows but someday I update my app and I want to add more rows. So now I am planning how to make it that rows which user change stay true but user still get new data with update. How can I do that? Is there any article for this?

Comment: What is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not much. I am thinking about it now because when I release my app I think it'll be late. I tried to google this but I found scheme updates but not just data updates with preserve user changes. One more thing I think this isn't easy to test, am I right? I mean has working app in phone (no problem) and tried to update it (without windows store).

Comment: If you're using SQL Compact and you found the `DatabaseSchemaUpdater` class you're on the right track. It allows for updating the database schema without affecting existing data (unless, of course, you're doing something like removing a column).

Comment: I found that DatabaseSchemaUpdater is mainly used for scheme update but I can used it for update data too, right? Check for database version and if it is old version then use loop and add all new data by db.add, am I right?